# Force page expiration in wicket 1.5.8

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

I'm trying to expire all previous versions of a given page with Wicket 1.5.8. In wicket 1.4, it was done by `getPage().getPageMap().clear()`. Now in wicket 1.5, page map is gone, and I can't figure out how to dot that.

My use case is that I have a wizard (http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/wizard/) to create/edit an entity. When the wizard is submitted, the user is redirected to the entities list. At this point I don't want the user to be able to use the browser back button to go back to the wizard in the state it was, and thus want to expire previous versions of the page with the wizard (I am using `getPageSettings().setRecreateMountedPagesAfterExpiry(true);` so the mounted page will be recreated in a blank state if the page expires when the user goes back, which is what I want).

Looking around I found the possibility to use `Session.get().clear();` which removes all pages from the Session (I don't know if the 1.4 version was removing all pages or just all versions of the page used to access the PageMap - which would be better for multi-tab support). However, using that works only partly, as the last page is not expired.

Supposing the wizard is mounted at `/wizard`, redirecting to `/list` at the end, the flow would be something like: `/wizard?1`, `/wizard?2`, `/wizard?3`, `/list`. Now when I use the back button, `/wizard?3` is not expired, although `/wizard?1` and `/wizard?2` are as expected. The session clearing and sending to the list page are done in the `onFinish` method of the wizard, which reads like this:

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
  Session.get().clear();
  Session.get().getFeedbackMessages().add(new FeedbackMessage(..));
  setResponsePage(ListPage.class);
}
```

So, come to the question itself: would anyone know how to get the expected behaviour, i.e. expiring `/wizard?3` as well?

Thanks

Note: `ListPage` is a bookmarkable page and I tried as well with `setResponsePage(new ListPage());`

---

**Update with what I finally did base on Andrea's suggestion**

It is to be noted that my application uses a custom session object extending wicket's `Session`; let's call it `AppSession`.

1. in `AppSession`, I added a `boolean clearRequested` attribute (defaults to false)
2. in `AppSession`, I added a static void method `requestClear()` which is just a shortcut to set *clearRequested* to true in the session
3. in the `onFinish()` of my wizard, just before calling `setResponsePage`, I call `AppSession.requestClear()`
4. lastly I just add a `RequestCycleListener` to my application.

   ```
   getRequestCycleListeners.add(new AbstractRequestCycleListener() {
     @Override
     public void onBeginRequest(RequestCycle cycle) {
       super.onBeginRequest(cycle);
       AppSession session = AppSesssion.get();
       if (session.isClearRequested()) {
         session.clear();
         session.setClearRequested(false);
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Now anytime I need to clear session after an action in order to expire pages, I juste call `AppSession.requestClear()` and in the next request the session is cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could clear your session in ListPage. Since this page is bookmarkable you could pass it a page parameter indicating that ListPage must get rid of the pages in session.

Comment: That works indeed; though passing a parameter to the page means the parameter will then be visible to the client and sit in the url.  

Additionally in the complete use case the wizard will redirect to the entity page when used to edit an entity.  

To avoid repeating the code and send that parameter, and thanks to your suggestion, I ended up creating a Page just to that effect (with 3 constructors corresponding to the three method signatures for `setResponsePage`) which just clear the session and then itself redirect to the page that was initally meant.  

Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: Note: in that session clearing page, I had to use `throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(..)` instead of `setResponsePage(..)` as the later would just lead to a blank page and stop there (probably because I was reaching that page through a `setResponsePage`), with nothing in the log though.

Comment: Well, my experiment with the custom page to clear before redirecting didn't actually work (I thought so but I had just forgotten to remove a systematic clear done in my bookmarkable page for tests purpose). With the redirection page the behaviour would be the same as without it. The page parameter option works of course very well, and I started first with passing the parameter and then in the constructor of the page, when the parameter for clearing was defined, clearing the session and redirecting to itself without that parameter. I ended up with a more generic version (see update in question)